# unable to use MaterialUI Datepicker,Dayjs with useFormik and Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datepicker, dayjs

I am using Material UI Date picker with day js,but the issue  that arising again and again is,'when I select the date on calender,1st time it updates in textfield and then it is not working.And also having problem in Yup like when touched 1st time it gives error means works perfectly but when removing the date from text field and left the field blank it does not work.'

codesandbox Link : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-datepicker-error-pdvt07

code:

```
    import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  TextField,
  Container,
  Typography,
  Stack,
  Button,
  Box
} from "@mui/material";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet-async";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { DesktopDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DesktopDatePicker";
import TodayIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Today";
import moment from "moment";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import InputAdornment from "@mui/material/InputAdornment";
import Autocomplete from "react-google-autocomplete";
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
// import useResponsive from "../../hooks/useResponsive";

export default function App() {
  // const navigate = useNavigate();
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string().required("First Name is required"),
    lastName: Yup.string()
      // .length(3, 'Last Name must be greater than 3 characters')
      .required("Last Name is required"),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email("Invalid email")
      .required("Please enter your email"),
    mobile: Yup.string()
      .length(10, "Mobile Number must be 10 digit")
      .required("Mobile Number is required"),
    dob: Yup.string().required("Dob is required"),
    passingYear: Yup.string().required("Passing out year is required"),
    location: Yup.string().required("Location is required"),
    occupation: Yup.string().required("Occupation is required"),
    address: Yup.string().required("Addres is required")
  });
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      mobile: "",
      dob: "",
      passingYear: "",
      location: "",
      address: "",
      occupation: ""
    },
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      console.log(values);
      // navigate(`/verify-otp?email=${values.email}`, { replace: true });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
        <Stack direction={"column"} spacing={3}>
          <Box>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              id="outlined-firstName-input"
              label="First Name"
              name="firstName"
              type={"text"}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.firstName}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {formik.touched.firstName && formik.errors.firstName && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.firstName}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              id="outlined-lastName-input"
              label="Last Name"
              name="lastName"
              type={"text"}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.lastName}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {formik.touched.lastName && formik.errors.lastName && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.lastName}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              id="outlined-email-input"
              label="Email address"
              name="email"
              type={"email"}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.email}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            />
            {formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.email}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              InputProps={{
                startAdornment: (
                  <InputAdornment position="start">+91</InputAdornment>
                )
              }}
              id="outlined-mobile-input"
              label="Mobile Number"
              type="tel"
              name="mobile"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.mobile}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {formik.touched.mobile && formik.errors.mobile && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.mobile}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DesktopDatePicker
                label="Date of birth"
                inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                value={dayjs(formik.values?.dob).format("DD-MM-YYYY") || ""}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  formik.setFieldValue(
                    "dob",
                    dayjs(newValue).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
                  );
                  formik.setFieldTouched("dob", true);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    sx={{
                      width: "100%"
                    }}
                    {...params}
                    name="dob"
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    error={formik.errors.dob && formik.touched.dob}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
            {formik.touched.dob && formik.errors.dob && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.dob}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
              <DatePicker
                views={["year"]}
                label="Passing year"
                maxDate={dayjs().subtract(1, "year")}
                value={formik.values.passingYear || ""}
                onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  formik.setFieldValue("passingYear", newValue?.format("YYYY"));
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    sx={{
                      width: "100%"
                    }}
                    {...params}
                    name="passingYear"
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    error={
                      formik.errors.passingYear && formik.touched.passingYear
                    }
                  />
                )}
              />

              {formik.touched.passingYear && formik.errors.passingYear && (
                <p
                  style={{
                    color: "red",
                    marginTop: "5px",
                    marginBottom: "-15px"
                  }}
                >
                  {formik.errors.passingYear}
                </p>
              )}
            </LocalizationProvider>
          </Box>

          <Box>
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              id="outlined-occupation-input"
              label="Occupation"
              name="occupation"
              type={"text"}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              value={formik.values.occupation}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {formik.touched.occupation && formik.errors.occupation && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.occupation}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box>
            <Autocomplete
              className="location"
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                paddingLeft: "13px",
                height: "8vh",
                border: "1px solid rgb(224,224,224)",
                borderRadius: "6px",
                fontSize: "17px",
                fontWeight: "500",
                color: "#212B36",
                backgroundColor: "#F9FAFB",
                "&:focus": {
                  borderWidth: "2px",
                  borderColor: "darken(#2f8f1f, 5%)",
                  fontSize: "20px"
                }
              }}
              apiKey={"AIzaSyABX4LTqTLQGg_b3jFOH8Z6_H5CDqn8tbc"}
              onPlaceSelected={(place) => {
                formik.setFieldValue("location", place?.formatted_address);
              }}
              types={["address"]}
              componentRestrictions={{ country: "us" }}
              name="location"
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
            />
            {formik.touched.location && formik.errors.location && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.location}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box
            sx={{
              width: "100%"
            }}
          >
            <TextField
              sx={{
                width: "100%"
              }}
              id="outlined-password-input"
              label="Addres"
              name="address"
              value={formik.values.address}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
              type="text"
              multiline
              rows={4}
              maxRows={6}
              autoComplete="off"
            />
            {formik.touched.address && formik.errors.address && (
              <p
                style={{
                  color: "red",
                  marginTop: "5px",
                  marginBottom: "-15px"
                }}
              >
                {formik.errors.address}
              </p>
            )}
          </Box>

          <Box ml={"auto"}>
            <Button fullWidth size="large" type="submit" variant="contained">
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Box>
        </Stack>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use dayjs format when trying to display the date. the date picker already formats the date for you in the textfield.

```js
 <DesktopDatePicker
                label="Date of birth"
                inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                value={formik.values?.dob}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                  formik.setFieldValue(
                    "dob",
                    newValue
                  );
                  formik.setFieldTouched("dob", true);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                  <TextField
                    sx={{
                      width: "100%"
                    }}
                    {...params}
                    name="dob"
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    error={formik.errors.dob && formik.touched.dob}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

Comment: yes you are right but it gives date in this format:   https://prnt.sc/TTlYHWx1tq-l   ,but I need only the accurate date like 12/04/1995

Comment: yeah, you can use `dayjs(dob).format("DD-MM-YYYY")` when trying to display the dob somewhere on ur website.

Comment: yes,exactly but If I use dayjs(dob).format("DD-MM-YYYY") in, formik.setFieldValue(
                    "dob",
                    dayjs(newValue).format("DD-MM-YYYY")
                  );      ..........will it be corrrect?

Comment: you cant do that since DatePicker uses ISO 8601 date format which is `2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z` and just formats it to you as `DD/MM/YYYY` in the textfield.

Comment: so `dob` would be stored as `2020-05-12T23:50:21.817Z` and you would do  `dayjs(dob).format('DD-MM-YYYY')` to format it when trying to display the date somewhere on ur site

Comment: ok,thanks @buga for your time and for explaining very well.....